# How to associate a really special openid to my careers.stackoverflow.com account?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, openid

In the profile section of my *careers.stackoverflow.com* account, there was an associated *openid* with the following information (182375 is my stackexchange.com user number):

> openid: Created for Stack Overflow Account Id 182375
>
> openid email: 182375@stackoverflow.com

and every other account has this *openid*, but unfortunately I mistakenly *deleted* it, because I thought I can add it later (I'm feeling sick after that decision).

How to *add* it again, and what was its usage, in another words what did I lost, and how to restore/recover it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You lost nothing really; that open id / user account is auto-generated in Careers when you login to Stack Overflow and use /jobs for the first time. It's an unfortunate side-effect of the way /jobs is currently implemented and it will eventually disappear as we integrate it more fully into SO.

It won't get added again because once the underlying Careers account is linked into your SO account it remains linked irrespective of what you do to the open ids.